# Constructing a Dataframe from two mismatched time series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: The raw csv data] [image: The reference data] I want to match two mismatched time series from two separate DateTimeIndexed dataframes (raw and ref), and combine them into a full dataframe, with a **full time series as the index** (thus some NaNs will be present as the df values)

How can I create a dataframe with a full DateTimeIndex (no missing values) that will 'house' these two time series that are each missing some values?
[image]

Below is what I tried: extract the columns of the two dfs (raw2 and ref2 here), index them, and slip them together in a new dataframe. Is this the correct approach? And if it is (which I doubt it is) why does my end result have so many NaNs- what am I doing wrong?

```
raw2 = raw2.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last').set_index('index')
    ref2 = ref2.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last').set_index('index')

rawdates = pd.to_datetime(raw2.index)
refdates = pd.to_datetime(ref2.index)


WE_COA4_S1 = raw2['AS_box2_COA4_132800061_WE']
AE_COA4_S1 = raw2['AS_box2_COA4_132800061_AE']
WE_COA4_S1.index = rawdates
AE_COA4_S1.index = rawdates

TEMP = ref2['UCAM_TEMP (degrees)']
TEMP.index = refdates

rng = pd.date_range('17/12/2015', freq='min', periods=1440*64, format = '%y-%d-%m')
   d = {'WorkingElectrode_COA4S1':WE_COA4_S1, 'AuxiliaryElectrode_COA4S1':AE_COA4_S1,
     'Temperature':TEMP}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index = rng)
```

There are way too many nans in this df. Why is it not accepting the values from the series?

Comment: This is very hard to follow (and probably correctly answer) without all the variables.  What is `raw2`, `ref2`, `refdates`, `dates`?  Can you edit the question with some of your original `csv` data (or at least example of it if you can't post exact data) and then describe what `DataFrame` format you'd like?

Comment: Sorry, being a typical mathematician I tend not to be able to convey anything... does this make more sense?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which represents the error?

Comment: Okay, does that make more sense?

Comment: you really need to add some example dataframes

Comment: Please add sample input for `raw2` and `ref2`, and add the result you desire for those samples.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how to upload sample dataframes... do these screenshots help?